# Intersection and Union of Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, find a condition on $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cup B = A \cap B$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ satisfy this condition.

I think this means $A = B$, and that I have to prove that the union of $A$ and $B$ is a subset of the intersection of $A$ and $B$, and vice versa.

I don't know how to do this though.

Suppose $x$ is in the complement of the union of $A$ and $B$. Then $x$ is not in $A$ and $x$ is not in $B$. Then $x$ is in the intersection of the complement of $A$ and the complement of $B$. 
Is proof by contradiction the right method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is $A=B$.  Suppose it's true.  Then clearly $A \cup B= A \cap B$.  Conversely, if $A\cup B= A \cap B$, then $A \subset A\cup B=A \cap B \subset B$, so $A\subset B$.  Similarly, $B \subset A$. Thus, $A=B$.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with what you are trying is that you are assuming there are elements that are outside of both $A$ and $B$, but that is unnecessary.  Imagine that there is $x\in A$ such that $x\notin B$.  Then $A\cup B$ would have an element in it that $A\cap B$ does not.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A \cup B = A \cap B$.  Let $a \in A$.  Since $a$ is in $A \cup B$ and $A \cup B = A \cap B$ then $a \in B$.  Thus $A \subseteq B$.  Similarly, if $b \in B$ then $b \in A$ so $ A = B$.  I think you can get the reverse implication yourself (?).